# How to make a pdf Generator with ionic?

Tags: html, angular, pdf, ionic2, generator

I want to make a pdf of the current page so the user can print it out but every page is dynamic so I will need a sort of a text to pdf generator to make it work.

It is an ionic2 app and is for like a recipe page so you can click on a button and it just makes a pdf out of the text.

Do you guys know how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet is probably this plugin:

https://github.com/cesarvr/pdf-generator

give your dynamic page section an id like 'pdf-area' and then select it in your .ts file like this:

```
let content = document.getElementById('pdf-area').innerHTML
```

you can then turn that into a file or print it like this

```
      cordova.plugins.pdf.htmlToPDF({
          data: content,
          type: "base64"
        },
          (success) => { 
           // you might have to turn the base64 into a binary blob to save it 
           // to a file at this point
        },

         (error) => console.log('error:', error);
   );

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

put your html in assets folder and give the html path like this.

In my case this path is working:
var file = 'file:///android_asset/www/assets/lolc.html';

```
generatePdf(){
    const before = Date.now();

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => {
      console.log('DEVICE READY FIRED AFTER', (Date.now() - before), 'ms');
      var file = 'file:///android_asset/www/assets/lolc.html';
      cordova.plugins.pdf.fromURL(file,{
        documentSize: "A4",
        landscape: "portrait",
        type: "share"
      }),
        (sucess) => console.log('sucess: ', sucess),
        (error) => console.log('error:', error);
    });
  }
```